# This AJAX Code Doesn't Work - Looking for elegant solution

Tags: posts, wp-query, loop, ajax

I am trying to utilize AJAX on my WordPress site for posts as a user scrolls. I followed [this](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/load-more-posts-ajax.html) tutorial but it has no effect on my WordPress website.

I have used a plugin that works, but I'd much rather learn how to do this without a plugin both to learn and also to avoid using unnecessary plugins. The below code does not work, instead all of my posts show up on the page despite posts per page being set to 5.

Help is appreciated!

**functions.php**

```
function misha_my_load_more_scripts() {

    global $wp_query; 
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script( 'my_loadmore', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/myloadmore.js', array('jquery') );

    wp_localize_script( 'my_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_params', array(
        'ajaxurl' => site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        'posts' => json_encode( $wp_query->query_vars ), 
        'current_page' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
        'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ) );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_loadmore' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'misha_my_load_more_scripts' );

function misha_loadmore_ajax_handler(){

      $args = array(
      'cat' => -21,
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'posts_per_page' => 5,
      'paged' => 1,
      'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'topics',
            'operator' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        )
    )

    );
      $args = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ), true );
      $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; //need next page to be loaded
      $args['post_status'] = 'publish';

    $the_query = new WP_Query ( $args ); 

    if($the_query->have_posts()) : 
      while($the_query->have_posts()) : 
         $the_query->the_post();

    get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );

        endwhile;

    endif;
    die; 
}

add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_{action}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}
```

**myloadmore.js**

```
jQuery(function($){
    var canBeLoaded = true, 
        bottomOffset = 2000; //I've played with this number to see if it was the offset calling posts too soon but it has no effect 

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var data = {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'query': misha_loadmore_params.posts,
            'page' : misha_loadmore_params.current_page
        };
        if( $(document).scrollTop() > ( $(document).height() - bottomOffset ) && canBeLoaded == true ){
            $.ajax({
                url : misha_loadmore_params.ajaxurl,
                data:data,
                type:'POST',
                beforeSend: function( xhr ){
                    canBeLoaded = false; 
                },
                success:function(data){
                    if( data ) {
                        $('#main').find('div:last-of-type').after( data ); 
                        canBeLoaded = true; 
                        misha_loadmore_params.current_page++;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**content.php**

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-6">
    <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" class="img-fluid"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">

    <?php
      $categories = get_the_category();
        if ( $categories ) :
            $deepChild = get_deep_child_category( $categories );
    ?>
    <p><?php echo $deepChild->name; ?></p>

      <?php endif; ?>

      <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

  </div>
</div><!-- END ROW-->
```

**front-page.php**

```
<div id="main" class="container-fluid">
  <?php misha_loadmore_ajax_handler(); ?>
</div><!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

**UPDATED CODE**

This following is updated code based on answers. I am posting this because it is still not working and I may be overlooking/misunderstanding something and I want to understand where I have gone wrong.

**functions.php**

```
function misha_my_load_more_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'my_loadmore', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/myloadmore.js',
        array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_loadmore' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'misha_my_load_more_scripts' );

function misha_loadmore_ajax_handler() {
    $args = json_decode( wp_unslash( $_POST['query'] ), true );
    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // load the next page

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
        endwhile;
    endif;

    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler' );        // Authenticated users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler' ); // Non-authenticated users
```

**myloadmore.js**

```
jQuery(function($){
    var canBeLoaded = true, // this param allows to initiate the AJAX call only if necessary
        // the distance (in px) from the page bottom when you want to load more posts,
        bottomOffset = ( $( '#main > div.post:last' ).offset() || {} ).top;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ( misha_loadmore_params.current_page >= misha_loadmore_params.max_page ) {
//          console.log( 'max_page reached; AJAX canceled' );
            return; // we've already reached the last page, so let's do no more AJAX.
        }
        var data = {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'query': misha_loadmore_params.posts,
            'page' : misha_loadmore_params.current_page
        };
        if( $(document).scrollTop() > ( $(document).height() - bottomOffset ) && canBeLoaded == true ){
            $.ajax({
                url : misha_loadmore_params.ajaxurl,
                data: data,
                type: 'POST',
                beforeSend: function( xhr ){
                    // you can also add your own preloader here
                    // you see, the AJAX call is in process, we shouldn't run it again until complete
                    canBeLoaded = false;
                },
                success:function(data){
                    if( data ) {
                        $('#main').find('div.post:last-of-type').after( data ); // where to insert posts
                        canBeLoaded = true; // the ajax is completed, now we can run it again
                        misha_loadmore_params.current_page++;

                        bottomOffset = ( $( '#main > div.post:last' ).offset() || {} ).top
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**content.php**

```
<div class="row post">
 <div class="col-sm-6">
    <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" class="img-fluid"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">

    <?php
      $categories = get_the_category();
        if ( $categories ) :
            $deepChild = get_deep_child_category( $categories );
    ?>
    <p><?php echo $deepChild->name; ?></p>

      <?php endif; ?>

      <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

  </div>
</div><!-- END ROW-->
```

**front-page.php**

```
 <?php
  $current_page = max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) );
  $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'cat'            => '-21',
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged'          => $current_page,
  ) );

  wp_localize_script( 'my_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_params', array(
    'ajaxurl'      => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php', 'relative' ),
    'posts'        => json_encode( $the_query->query_vars ),
    'current_page' => $current_page,
    'max_page'     => $the_query->max_num_pages
  ) );
?>
  <div id="main" class="container-fluid">
    <?php
      if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
          while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
              // Should match the one in misha_loadmore_ajax_handler().
              get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
          endwhile;
      endif;
    ?>
  </div>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

</div><!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

Comment: **You should not pass unfiltered args directly to WP_Query.** What happens when a user opens the devtools and runs `$.ajax({ url : misha_loadmore_params.ajaxurl, data: { post_status: 'private' } })` ? They can read all your private posts. What if you have WooCommerce and they use `{ post_type: 'shop_order', post_status: 'any' }`? _Never trust user input_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Working Code Based On My Previous Answer

*Without using nonce.. but you can check the previous answer on how you can implement a nonce check.* And the code is based on *your* code.

#### `misha_my_load_more_scripts()` in `functions.php`

```
function misha_my_load_more_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'my_loadmore', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/myloadmore.js',
        array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_loadmore' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'misha_my_load_more_scripts' );
```

#### `misha_loadmore_ajax_handler()` in `functions.php`

```
function misha_loadmore_ajax_handler() {
    $args = json_decode( wp_unslash( $_POST['query'] ), true );
    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // load the next page

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );
        endwhile;
    endif;

    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler' );        // Authenticated users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler' ); // Non-authenticated users
```

#### `front-page.php` (the `#main` DIV)

```
$current_page = max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) );
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'cat'            => '-21',
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged'          => $current_page,
) );

wp_localize_script( 'my_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_params', array(
    'ajaxurl'      => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php', 'relative' ),
    'posts'        => json_encode( $the_query->query_vars ),
    'current_page' => $current_page,
    'max_page'     => $the_query->max_num_pages
) );
?>
    <div id="main" class="container-fluid">
        <?php
            if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
                    // Should match the one in misha_loadmore_ajax_handler().
                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );
                endwhile;
            endif;
        ?>
    </div>
<?php
wp_reset_postdata();
```

#### `myloadmore.js` and `content.php`

*No changes.*

### UPDATE

Actually, in my code (the one I actually tested with), **I don't have the `tax_query` parameter**, but I mistakenly included it in the above code in the previous version of this answer (not the other one on this page).

Because a `tax_query` like the following — which doesn't specify the required `terms` [parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) — would result in an `0 = 1` in the MySQL query, and eventually leads to no results (i.e. no posts):

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    ...
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'topics',
            'operator' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            // missing the required 'terms' parameter
        ),
    ),
) );
```

So make certain to use `tax_query` with the proper parameters.

And you may also want to use/check my `myloadmore.js` [script](https://pastebin.com/3kYV79xJ)?

Comment: This code doesn't return any errors but none of the posts load.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the XHR request - in Chrome, `Ctrl + Shift + I` and go to the Network -> XHR tab. Click on the request name and check its Response.

Comment: The XHR tab has a name of admin-ajax.php and it's response: "This request has no response data available"  Under Headers it has a green dot with a Status Code of 200 OK. I have updated my question with the new code under my original code which may help find if I am doing something wrong. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I should've not included the `tax_query` in my answer. Nonetheless, check the updated answer. Hopefully this time it works..

Comment: Have you checked the update? Did it work?

Comment: I have tried this update, and the AJAX does work to an extent however it comes with three problems I've been trying to solve over the last couple of days. 1) It doesn't load all posts. In the myloadmore.js using div.post as you do, It seems to repeat the first 5 posts then show only a handful of the next posts before it continues to load. I tried just using div instead of div.post but this seems to just cause it to loop the same 5 posts over and over. 2) Using tax_query is essential to my query 3) It seems to be showing previously unpublished posts (possibly unrelated)

Comment: I also updated the code in the question in case there's an error on my end, thanks again!

Comment: Another Update: I can seem to confirm that after it hits the 6th post, it resets back to the first post and continues to do this about 6 times before loading other posts, but some of these posts also repeat themselves. I cannot seem to find the cause in the query for this, and it did not occur when posts were not loading with AJAX

Comment: I got this working! It turns out I needed to add the post class to the content.php to align with the myloadmore.js call. I have it there now, and this solves all the above problems with the exception of I need the taxonomy call. I will run a test on this and post an update here

Comment: I was able to get my tax_query to work however there's some kind of issue with the posts_per_page in the WP_Query. At it's current setting (5) it loads for a while but not all posts. (I have about 30 posts right now on the blog and it will add to it with time). However if I set it to say, 12 posts per page it will load until the end, but I think that's because there's only 30 posts. So something seems to be stopping it from making the call again.

Comment: If your `posts_per_page` setting is 5, of course the posts displayed/returned in a single request would be 5, and on scroll, the next 5 posts would be loaded. And that scrolling scenario would continue until all posts are loaded.

Comment: And if you're specifically having problems with the taxonomy query, then (you should) post a new question - or update the question and please add the `tax_query` you use.

Comment: I marked this as answered as the code does load it in. I was able to get tax_query to work as it existed in my question. It did not seem to negatively effect the AJAX load. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you've now set the proper `terms`? Because otherwise - `tax_query` without a `terms`, I don't think the query will work. :) Anyway, thank you for accepting the answer!

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your code, such as:

1. The original [code](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/load-more-posts-ajax.html) relies upon the global `$wp_query` object; see the `global $wp_query;` in the `misha_my_load_more_scripts()` function. But your code is using a custom `WP_Query` instance, which is `$the_query` and which is used in the `misha_loadmore_ajax_handler()` function.
2. The `misha_loadmore_ajax_handler()` is an AJAX handler/callback and hence it shouldn't be called from `div#main` like so:

   ```
   <div id="main" class="container-fluid">
     <?php misha_loadmore_ajax_handler(); ?>
   </div><!-- END CONTAINER -->
   ```

So the original code does work; however, for custom `WP_Query` requests such as the `$the_query` in your case, you'd need to put/define the AJAX JS variables *after* you make the `WP_Query` request.

And here's how you could do that:

1. First off, I'm using the default code (JS/PHP) as provided on [the page](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/load-more-posts-ajax.html), and I'm using the "*load posts on scroll (lazy load)*" script/option.
2. Secondly, this is my `misha_my_load_more_scripts()` function:

   ```
   function misha_my_load_more_scripts() {
       // register our main script but do not enqueue it yet
       wp_register_script( 'my_loadmore', 'URL/to/the/load-more-script', array('jquery') );

       wp_enqueue_script( 'my_loadmore' );
   }
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'misha_my_load_more_scripts' );
   ```
3. And my "main" `div` (the posts container):

   ```
   $current_page = max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) );
   $the_query = new WP_Query([
       'posts_per_page' => 5,
       'paged'          => $current_page,
   ]);
   ?>
       <div id="main">
           <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
               // This should match the one in misha_loadmore_ajax_handler().
               get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );
           endwhile; ?>
       </div>
       <script>
           var misha_loadmore_params = {
               ajaxurl: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php', 'relative' ); ?>',
               posts: '<?php echo json_encode( $the_query->query_vars ); ?>',
               current_page: <?php echo $current_page; ?>,
               max_page: <?php echo $the_query->max_num_pages; ?>
           };
       </script>
   <?php
   wp_reset_postdata();
   ```
4. Those are the only changes I made and the original `misha_loadmore_ajax_handler()` code ([on that page](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/load-more-posts-ajax.html)) can be used as it is.

I have tried and tested the/my code, and it is working as expected. And although I didn't use your code, I believe you can easily implement my code with your code/concept.

### UPDATE

If you'd like to use `wp_localize_script()` (and it might be better particularly if you wish to include translated text in the JS object/data), then you need to enqueue the load-more script in the footer:

```
wp_register_script( 'my_loadmore', 'URL/to/the/load-more-script', array('jquery'),
  'version', true );
```

And then in the "main" `div`, remove the `<script>...</script>` and add this before the `wp_reset_postdata()`:

```
wp_localize_script( 'my_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_params', [
    'ajaxurl'      => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php', 'relative' ),
    'posts'        => json_encode( $the_query->query_vars ),
    'current_page' => $current_page,
    'max_page'     => $the_query->max_num_pages,
    // These two are optional.
    'my_text'      => __( 'My text', 'text-domain' ),
    'security'     => wp_create_nonce( 'my-load-more-posts' ),
] );
```

And as you can see, I've included one translation there: `My text` (`misha_loadmore_params.my_text`).

**Using a Nonce**

In the above localized data, I've also included a nonce (`security`), which is specifically useful when your AJAX PHP handler is making some write operations — e.g. updating a metadata.

And you can send it to the PHP handler like so:

```
// This is set in the load-more script.
var data = {
  'action': 'loadmore',
  'query': misha_loadmore_params.posts,
  'page' : misha_loadmore_params.current_page,
  'security': misha_loadmore_params.security
};
```

And then in the PHP handler, you can do so to verify the nonce:

```
function misha_loadmore_ajax_handler(){
    check_ajax_referer( 'my-load-more-posts', 'security' );

    ...
    wp_die();
}
```

*PS: [This](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/drvaWm.js) is my load-more script, with only one difference compared to the original one, which is the `misha_loadmore_params.security` part.*

Comment: an improvement could be creating a [nonce](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_nonce/) and using [wp_localize_script()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to set the ajax_url and the nonce for the ajax call

Comment: Thanks @aloMalbarez. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @SallyCJ Sorry for getting back to this late - I was side tracked. I am following your code but I receive a 400 (Bad Request) when calling for admin-ajax.php. I have checked my wp-admin folder and admin-ajax is certainly there. Unfortunately I cannot seem to test this code until this is resolved. This happened with both the original code you provided and the Update.

Comment: @user5854648, I've posted a new answer.. try the code and if it works, you can accept the answer.. ;)

Comment: @SallyCJ could you specify where the PHP handler goes (the last block of code)? I tried putting it as the first line of code in the misha_loadmore_ajax_handler() function in the functions.php (the same functions.php you have in your answer). I'm also not sure where the 'my-load-more-posts' is referring to. Right now it's loading the first 5 posts but nothing else is entering upon scroll. If it sounds like I'm doing it right please let me know if I should provide my current code.

Comment: Both the `misha_my_load_more_scripts()` and `misha_loadmore_ajax_handler()`  functions should go in the theme `functions.php` file, just as you could see in the other answer. But can I see your current code? Maybe something is missing..