# AJAX Breaking Offset Argument In WP Query

Tags: wp-query, loop, ajax, offsets

I have been using AJAX on my website successfully and for my category.php page I need to use the offset argument. Unfortunately, AJAX creates complications with offset and I get the same posts looping over and over. I consulted the WordPress codex but I couldn't not figure out how to apply a solution to my particular WP_Query. Anyone that can help I'd be grateful, I can provide more code if necessary as well. Thanks!

**category.php**

```
<?php
    $category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
    $cat_id = $category->cat_ID;
    $current_page = max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'category__in' => array($cat_id), 
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'paged'          => $current_page,
    ) );

    $_SESSION['count'] = 1;
    wp_localize_script( 'my_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_params', array(
        'ajaxurl'      => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php', 'relative' ),
        'posts'        => json_encode( $the_query->query_vars ),
        'current_page' => $current_page,
        'max_page'     => $the_query->max_num_pages
    ) );
?>

<div id="main" class="container feed-container">
    <div class="row mx-auto align-items-center post">      
    <?php if ($the_query->have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php $count = 0; ?>
        <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); get_template_part( 'parts/content', get_post_format() ); ?>
            <?php $count++;

            $_SESSION['count']=$_SESSION['count']+1;
            ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div><!-- END ROW -->
</div><!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

**AJAX**

```
jQuery(function($){
    var canBeLoaded = true,
                bottomOffset = 1300;


    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ( misha_loadmore_params.current_page >= misha_loadmore_params.max_page ) {
//          console.log( 'max_page reached; AJAX canceled' );
            return;
        }
        var data = {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'query': misha_loadmore_params.posts,
            'page' : misha_loadmore_params.current_page
        };
        if( $(document).scrollTop() > ( $(document).height() - bottomOffset ) && canBeLoaded == true ){

            $.ajax({
                url : misha_loadmore_params.ajaxurl,
                data: data,
                type: 'POST',
                beforeSend: function( xhr ){
                    canBeLoaded = false;
                },
                success:function(data){
                    if( data ) {
                        $('#main').find('div.post:last-of-type').after( data ); 
                        canBeLoaded = true;
                        misha_loadmore_params.current_page++;

                        // bottomOffset = ( $( '#main > div.post:last' ).offset() || {} ).top
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Where's your PHP code which handles the AJAX request?

Comment: Hi @SallyCJ funny, you were the one to help me with my last AJAX question, this is actually just about the same code you helped me develop. I didn't include originally because I wasn't sure if the AJAX itself was the issue or WordPress parameters. Either way I have added the AJAX code please let me know if I can provide anything else. This is my first foray into AJAX so I'm learning a lot! Thanks!

Comment: I did think of that. But I guess I just wanted to be sure about it. :) Anyway, check my answer. I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm guessing this is a follow-up to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/331002/137402). And based on [my answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/332155/137402) there, you can use/add the `offset` parameter like so:

1. In `category.php`, just set the preferred offset:

   ```php
   $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
       'category__in'   => array( $cat_id ),
       'post_type'      => 'post',
       'posts_per_page' => 5,
       'paged'          => $current_page,
       'offset'         => 1, // set offset
   ) );
   ```
2. In `misha_loadmore_ajax_handler()` (the *PHP function* which processes the AJAX requests), add this right before `$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );`:

   ```php
   if ( isset( $args['offset'] ) ) {
       $offset = absint( $args['offset'] );
       $args['offset'] = absint( ( $args['paged'] - 1 ) * $args['posts_per_page'] ) + $offset;
   }
   ```

That's all. No changes necessary in the JavaScript parts.